# Existence of the Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm seeing Laplace transforms for the first time, and I'm having trouble understanding the criteria for deciding when they exist.

I've read a few websites and books that seem to say that we only need a function $f(t)$ to be piecewise continuous for $t \geq 0$ and of exponential order for the Laplace transform to exist. However, the function $f(t) = t^{-1/2}$ is not even defined at $0$, but $\mathcal{L}[t^{-1/2}] = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{s}}$, and so it appears that these requirements can be relaxed a little. If we then consider $g(t) = t^{-2}$, apparently this transform does not exist. But it is definitely true that $ t^{-2} < e^t $ for large enough $t$, and so I don't see how $t^{-1/2}$ is any "better" than $t^{-2}$.

Comment: A sufficient condition is that $t \mapsto f(t) e^{\alpha t} dt $ is integrable for some $\alpha$. This allows $f$ to have infinite values (as long as the integrability condition is satisfied).

Comment: I've seen that condition one too, but I was really hoping for an idea of how the conditions I have listed interact with the examples I have given. If that question is somehow unreasonable, how would one look at $t^{-2}$ and decide that it has no Laplace transform?

Comment: Well, $t \mapsto \frac{1}{t^2}e^{\alpha t}$ is not integrable for any $\alpha$ (because of its behaviour near $t=0$, whereas $t \mapsto\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}e^{\alpha t}$ is integrable. Note that $t \mapsto \frac{1}{t^2}e^{\alpha t}u(t-t_0)$ **is** integrable for any $t_0 >0$.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks.